# Scroll horizontally on ionic with rtl list

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a list in an RTL document. When I use ion-scroll for direction x it adds scroll to the left side of the content, which makes it impossible to scroll to the right. How can I fix this?

Comment: how did you figure it out